# WPF TextBox ValidationRule binding

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, textbox, validationrules

I need to add ValidationRule to the TextBox programmatically in WPF. 
I'm trying something like:

```
Binding binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(myTextBox, TextBox.TextProperty);
binding.ValidationRules.Clear();
binding.ValidationRules.Add(myValidationRule);
```

But BindingOperations.GetBinding return null. Why?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the API:

> Return Value
>
> Type: System.Windows.Data.Binding The Binding object set on the given
>   property or Nothing if no Binding object has been set.

So apparantly there is no Bindig object set.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.getbinding.aspx)

Comment: Can I somehow add validation rule without binding?

Comment: I would advise you to read the article at this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2007/10/02/data-validation-in-3-5.aspx